# flutter convert map to list without key

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert a map like

```
 {
  "name": "my name",
  "date": "14 Feb 2020",
  "days": "15",
 }
```

Into something like

```
[
 "my name",
 "14 Feb 2020"
 "15"
]
```

Basically converting map values into List.

I've tried

> list.add(name) and so on

but there will be problems if there is many data. Is there any way to iterate to get the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a value list using the `values` getter.

```dart
final map = {
  "name": "my name",
  "date": "14 Feb 2020",
  "days": "15",
};

map.values.toList(); // <---- Here
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I used this but it didn't work at first and turned out I was converting straight from a class. So I had to turn that class toJson() first and then I used that method and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map myMap = {"name":"mike", "age":"12};
List myList = myMap.values.toList();
```